# Is there any way so that I can do create-react-app successfully?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner at React js. From a tutorial, I was trying to execute: `npx create-react-app todo-list`.
But it fails every time. I get these types of errors

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf: Socket timeout
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-17T10_59_28_029Z-debug-0.log
```

[image]

My download speed is 380kb/s

Comment: Hi. Please share relevant info (such as error messages) as ***text*** so that anyone else facing the same issue can search and find your question. Here's a thread about an issue that looks the same... https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5496#issuecomment-1273286571

Comment: ...and another: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3374

Comment: Can't say what is the problem from these info. npx internally uses nodejs, nodejs uses os functionalities, so it can come from anywhere. Make sure your OS and node js are latest stable ones